# Apache Ignite: IN query too slow

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I'm trying to run queries on Apache Ignite after populating it from PostgreSQL db. Problem is that

Suppoe I've 2 caches A and B, having 8700 and 10,000 records respectively.
When I run queries independent queries

`SELECT id FROM "pcm".pcm WHERE code=1222;`

`SELECT id, name FROM "tn".tn WHERE id IN (6838);`

Here, `6838` is returned by the 1st query.
These queries take around 6ms and 10ms resp. 
But when I run

`SELECT id, name FROM "tn".tn WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "pcm".pcm WHERE code=1222);`

This takes around 9000ms.

Can somebody help me to figure out why this query is taking so much time?
PS: I have not built any indexes on ignite as of now.

Answer (score 5):

Operator IN doesn't use indexes. You should replace IN with joins:

https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#section-sql-performance-and-usability-considerations

Comment: I'm currently executing all queries without an index. Even I replaced IN query with `inner join`, it's still taking 3398ms which is still too much than independent queries time combined.

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, tn.name
from 
    pcm.pcm
    inner join
    tn.tn using (id)
where pcm.code = 1222
```

Comment: `6838` is a result of 1st query in question. I don't think your query is same as intended one.

Comment: @ajaysingh Thanks, fixed